# Error slider carousel Boostrap in codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

My website already connect with database, but somehow bootstrap carousel that I use for slider not working... What I expected the image will be like this:
< image > < image > < image > 
But what I get is:

```
<image>  
<image> 
<image>
```

I don't know what's wrong with my code... Can somebody help me?

```
 <!--- Slider -->    
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <?php foreach ($slider as $slider): ?>
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url('upload/slider/'.$slider->image)?>">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3><?php echo $slider->name?></h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?> 
            </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                <span class="sr-only"> previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="=#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                <span class="sr-only"> next </span> 
            </a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this and work fine.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" >
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <?php for($j=0; $j<count($slider); $j++) {?>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $j; ?>" class=""></li>
        <?php }; ?>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" >
        <?php $i=1;
        foreach ($slider as $slider) { ?>

            <div class="item <?php echo ($i==1) ? "active" : "" ?>">

                <img src="<?php echo base_url('upload/slider/'.$slider->image) ?>" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" title="">

                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3><?php echo $slider->name?></h3>
                </div>

            </div>
        <?php $i++; } ?>
    </div>

     <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
       <span class="sr-only"> previous</span>
     </a>

    <a class="right carousel-control" href="=#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
       <span class="sr-only"> next </span> 
    </a>

    <div class="carousel-line"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If it's help for you. Please give vote find solutions for others